# virtualenvwrapper.sh error showing at terminal startup

Tags: python, linux

As I'm starting to learn Python programming, I installed virtualenvwrapper via these commands:

```
# Install distribute: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute
wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python distribute_setup.py

# Install pip http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip
sudo easy_install pip

# Install virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenv

# Install virtualenvwrapper
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh
echo source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` >> $HOME/.bashrc

# IMPORTANT
# Go to the working directory

# Start a working environment virtualenv
mkvirtualenv <working environment name>

# Install all the requirements for the working environment
pip -E $VIRTUAL_ENV install -r requirements.txt
```

I've been getting this error every time I open a terminal (via guake)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 72, in main
    backupCount=1,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 112, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.py", line 64, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 827, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 846, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ahim/$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR/hook.log'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

I'm using Linux Mint 10 64bit GNOME.

Is there any way to solve this error I see in the terminal?

I've tried searching via google but none of them seems to fix this problem.

Thank you in advance.

===Edit===

This is what is written in /home/user/.bashrc

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh 2> /dev/null
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR=/tmp
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 16):

[According to this](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issue/95/error-on-opening-shell), it seems to be an error with the APT package on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint.

I have installed virtualenvwrapper through APT first, then removed it and installed it via pip.

```
apt-get install virtualenvwrapper
apt-get remove virtualenvwrapper
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

The APT package has added the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper` but didn't remove it. This is the file that's causing problems.

The recommended solution is to remove this file and the errors stop appearing. (Weirdly, simply renaming the file was not enough).

Comment: That's exactly what I did too; I used apt-get for virtualenvwrapper only to find out it's older than I'd like it to be. Upon using pip to install virtualenvwrapper I received the error as in the openingpost. In order to use virtualenvwrapper after removing the file you suggested I still need to do `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` before I can use it though.

Comment: The solution of using pip install worked for me. I am on Debian and was using the APT package for virtualenvwrapper.

Answer (score 6):

For those who come afterwards, I had the same problem on Ubuntu 12 and solved this way:

1. Switch to correct user:

   ```
   su username
   ```
2. Make sure your WORKON_HOME variable is set to the path you want it to be (defaults to ~/.virtualenv)

   ```
   WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenv
   ```
3. Then add these two lines before your source command:

   ```
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR="$WORKON_HOME"
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR="$WORKON_HOME"
   ```
4. Then save and re-source your bashrc:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

Comment: It works, but it's not fixing the issue. You shouldn't have to define these variables manually.

Comment: What do you mean by working but not fixing? What do you mean by manually?-- if you put the variables in the bashrc file, it should always work.

Comment: What I mean is that there's no reason to define these variables outside of virtualenvwrapper.sh unless you have a good reason to. "It solves a *weird* problem" does not qualify for good reason. Your solution doesn't fix the problem as much as patches a workaround. This introduces unnecessary complexity to your system that quickly piles up to make things unmaintainable. It's similar to accessing and modifying private variables of an API and calling a problem solved.

Comment: I appreciate your point; that's true. Unfortunately, I don't know enough theory to do anything but patch it. And to be honest, it appears no one else on the web does either -- I've looked. 

Since I work on a Mac, I've done extensive commenting in my .profile to make the pile up a little neater.

You're right though, and I welcome another solution.

Comment: I was in a very similar situation and wrote what I found in my answer below. Read the comments in the bug report I linked if you want to understand the issue better.

Comment: Yes, that does seem like a more complete solution. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues.  I removed any settings in my ~/.bashrc related to virtualenv, eg:

```
 # virtualenv
 #export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs
 #source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

That fixed the errors.

Answer (score 1):

For complete removal under debian remove following:

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper*
/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

That worked for me

Also delete files from python's **dist-packages** (depends on distro and python version)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR` environment variable. Add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR=/tmp
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response John Keyes but same error still shows. Edited the first post with the one written at .bashrc. Hope we get this sorted out soon :( Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem while trying to make it work on Debian.  I needed to run it as a user other than the X user, but it used the `~/.virtualenvs` directory of the X user for `WORKON_HOME`, `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR` and `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR`.

It works now that I set those variables to a proper directory in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the export command like this:

```
$export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR = "/path/to/the/hook.log"
```

In my case, the hook.log was created in the same path that my virtualenvwrapper config where in /home/my_user/.virtualenvs, so what I did was to export the variable like this

```
$export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR = "./"
```